# How to dynamically create instance of a class automatically in python

Tags: python, class

I have a class and I want to create dynamically instances of that class. I don't know the exact number of instances so that I dont want to create that classes by a known variable like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age, gender):
        self.age=age
        self.gender=gender

P1=Person(23, "M")
P2=Person(64, "F")
P3=Person(12, "M")
```

I am looking for sth like

```
i=0
maxPopulation=10
while i< maxPopulation:
    Person(randomx, randomy)
    i+=1
```

But that way I don't know how to access the instances. During the runtime.

I am not looking for a random function.

Comment: put the instances in a list or a dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you put them in a list or other collection?

Comment: Yep the list might be a solution but I fear that the list with be extended more and more because the instances come and go as during the runtime "people may disappear" or "new people may appear"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to a list.

```
i=0
maxPopulation=10
people = []
while i< maxPopulation:
    people.append(Person(randomx, randomy))
    i+=1
```

Or, cleaned up a bit to be more Pythonic:

```
maxPopulation=10
people = []
for _ in range(maxPopulation):
    people.append(Person(randomx, randomy))
```

Or even *more* Pythonic:

```
max_population = 10
people = [Person(randomx, randomy) for _ in range(max_population)]
```